# 2016: which Power Functions for controllable car?

Tags: power-functions

I want to make a car or truck that can be driven by a controller.

**Q: what Power Functions sets do I need in 2016? Any other suggestions?**

- I have no Technic nor Power Functions
- I'm willing to buy anything
- I am at an Expert level for brick-based construction
- ...but know almost nothing about beam-based construction
- my existing library of beam parts comes from whatever parts happened to come with brick-based sets

References from older questions:

- [What are the best options for building a LEGO RC car?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-are-the-best-options-for-building-a-lego-rc-car)
- [Does the Power Functions IR Remote Control 8885 make a good remote for a car?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/845/does-the-power-functions-ir-remote-control-8885-make-a-good-remote-for-a-car)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have no technic and no power functions you will need to get quite a lot. You could buy small technic sets to get enough parts to build the moving parts and you your current collection, or buy a big set and just add power functions to it. The [Customized Pickup Truck](http://brickset.com/sets/42029-1) is a good starter set that has all the right moving parts, but pretty much any Technic truck/car contains steering and a drive chain that you can attach a motor to.

For steering I recommend the [servo motor](http://brickset.com/sets/88004-1/Servo-Motor). As a kid I spent a lot of time making cars that would lock left or right but not flick back to exactly straight afterwards.

[image: 88004 Servo Motor]

For propulsion you have a whole array of motor options, the biggest and strongest (but also the slowest) is the [XL motor](http://brickset.com/sets/8882-1/XL-Motor). I've seen the Customized Pickup Truck converted to full RC using two M motors.

[image: 8882 XL Motor]

One [IR receiver](http://brickset.com/sets/8884-1/IR-Receiver) can control two wires so if you're only thinking about propulsion and steering one will do.

[image: 8884 IR reveiver]

You'll need a battery pack. I prefer there [one that takes AA](http://brickset.com/sets/8881-1/Battery-Box)s because years from now AA battery will still be purchasable and may be even longer lasting, plus you can keep spares near by, as opposed to the [Lego rechargeable battery](http://brickset.com/sets/8878-1/Rechargeable-Battery-Box) which will wear out over time and not be available forever.

[image: 8881 Battery Box]

And finally a remote. The [speed remote](http://brickset.com/sets/8879-1/IR-Speed-Remote-Control) lets you control the speed of the motors, not just forward/backwards at a fixed speed. However you'll need some extra parts to make left/right steering make sense on there. The other option is  the basic [IR remote](http://brickset.com/sets/8885-1/IR-Remote-Control). Either one can control two functions.

[image: 8879 Speed Remote]
[image: 8885 IR Remote]